# por que me sale el error de que no encontro el recurso del layout al firmar el apk de mi aplicacion

Tags: java, android

[image: ierror al firmar la aplicacion]

tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo el error el cuando intento firmar el apk me genera de que no encontro el recurso layout tal como se ve en la imagen en cambio el layout que no fue encontrado esta en la carpeta de layout o es que lo estoy incluyendo mal  alguien que aya tenido el mismo error una manito....
layout activity_list_farm




layout Conten_list_farm

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Una imagen sirve de muy poco en este caso. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/152168/edit), poniendo el contenido en XML (texto) de los dos layout que aparecen en rojo, a la izquierda, y de la parte que te marca error en `PharmacyFragment.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que no encuentra algunos de los ficheros .XML. Te explico, ve a vista del proyecto y verás que esos ficheros que al lado pone (debug), están dentro de la carpeta app/debug. Debes pasarlos a la carpeta app/release y hacer la correspondiente refactorización. Verás como cuando vuelvas a vista android  desaparece la palabra (debug) al lado de esos ficheros. Y ya podrás firmarla sin problemas. Pruébalo y ya nos cuentas, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Aplícare tu solución y les cuento como me fue de antemano gracias